# Find $3a+b+3c+4d$ if $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-4&-15\\2&7\end{smallmatrix}\right)^{100}=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Let
$\begin{pmatrix} -4 & -15 \\ 2 & 7 \end{pmatrix}^{100} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$.
Find $3a + b + 3c + 4d$.
I've gotten this answer for the matrix to the 100th power (via calculator), but it's HUGE. I need a simpler method to find it. Can I get some tips please?

Comment: Hint: diagonalisation works

Comment: This question features in Michael Penn's video: [Hopefully you remember the ???? theorem for this matrix problem!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mXwDHUI0SQ).
There is also another post related to the same matrix: [Find a formula for $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -4 & -15 \\ 2 & 7 \end{smallmatrix}\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2901257).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}-4&-15\\2&7\end{pmatrix}$. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we get $A^2-3A+2I=O$. Thus $A^n$ can be represented as the sum of $A$ and $I$; that is, there are $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $A^n = a_n A + b_n I$. Then
\begin{align}
A^{n+1}&=a_n A^2+b_n A\\
&=a_n(3A-2I)+b_n A\\
&=(3a_n +b_n)A-2a_n I.
\end{align}
We get
$$\begin{cases}
a_{n+1}=3a_n+b_n\\
b_{n+1} = -2a_n.
\end{cases}$$
Now we can construct the linear recurrence relation of second order for $a_n$:
$$
a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}-2a_n.
$$
Thus, $a_n = c_1 2^n + c_2$ for some $c_1,c_2$. Since $a_1=1$ and $a_2=3$, $a_n = 2^n -1$, and $b_n = -2^n+2$. Also,
\begin{align}
A^{100}&= a_{100}A+b_{100}I\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
-4a_{100}+b_{100} & -15a_{100}\\
2a_{100} & 7a_{100} + b_{100}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
3a+b+3c+4d&=3(-4a_{100}+b_{100})-15a_{100}+3\cdot 2a_{100} +4(7a_{100}+b_{100})\\
&=7a_{100}+7b_{100}\\
&=7(2^{100}-1)+7(-2^{100}+2)\\
&=7.
\end{align}

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* If $A$ is that matrix, then $A^2=3A-2I$ and so $A^n = (2^n-1)A-(2^n-2)I$.

Then you can compute $3a + b + 3c + 4d$ directly for $A^n$.

Or you can set $$\varphi\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}=3a + b + 3c + 4d$$ and notice that $\varphi(A)=\varphi(I)=7$ and so $\varphi(A^n) = (2^n-1)\varphi(A)-(2^n-2)\varphi(I)=7$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote $A^n=\begin{pmatrix}a_n&b_n\\c_n&d_n\end{pmatrix}$.

We have $\operatorname{Tr}(A)=3$, $\det(A)=2$ so the characteristic polynomial is $\chi_A(t)=t^2-3t+2=(t-1)(t-2)$; and we have the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$ a $\lambda_2=2$.

We can see that $(2,5)A=(2,5)$ and $A\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. (These are simply the [left and right eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Left_and_right_eigenvectors) corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1=1$.)

By induction we can get that $(2,5)A^n=(2,5)$ and $A^n\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ (for each integer $n$ such that $n\ge0$).
By rewriting these equalities using $a_n,\ldots,d_n$ we get several expressions which are constant (independent of $n$):
\begin{align*}
2a_n+5c_n&=2\\
2b_n+5d_n&=5\\
3a_n-b_n&=3\\
3c_n-d_n&=-1
\end{align*}
By adding the last three we get:
\begin{align*}
(3a_n-b_n)+(2b_n+5d_n)+(3c_n-d_n)&=3+5-1\\
3a_n+b_n+3c_n+4d_n&=7
\end{align*}